# ImportError: No module named endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Was working while setup in a samples dir downloaded from github, but now that I've built my own API, the dev server starts but throws this error when hitting it with CURL:

> $ dev_appserver.py ./app.yaml

```
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:38,215 api_server.py:275] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54462
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:38,225 api_server.py:265] Starting gRPC API server at: http://localhost:54464
WARNING  2019-03-31 21:48:38,227 dispatcher.py:338] Your python27 micro version is below 2.7.12, our current production version.
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:38,386 dispatcher.py:256] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:38,395 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:48,055 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 96100
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:48,076 module.py:861] default: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 404 -
ERROR    2019-03-31 21:48:48,113 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/me/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/activitylogs_api/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    import endpoints
ImportError: No module named endpoints
INFO     2019-03-31 21:48:48,120 module.py:861] default: "GET /_ah/api/activitylogs/v1/list HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

However python -m pip list shows these:

> google-endpoints                       4.8.0
>   google-endpoints-api-management        1.11.0

Does the dev server run under the context of some other environment?  It was working while in a different samples folder but not here.  There's also a ./lib folder with the requirements installed by this command:

> pip install --target lib --requirement requirements.txt
>   --ignore-installed

which of course, includes endpoints...

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 237.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.83
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.74
beta 2019.02.22
bq 2.0.42
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2019.03.01
gsutil 4.37
kubectl 2019.03.01
```

Here is (the beginning of) main.py:

```
# [START imports]
import endpoints
from endpoints import message_types
from endpoints import messages
from endpoints import remote
from datetime import datetime
# [END imports]
```

What's interesting is that if I enter python and try the import I get a different error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:17:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import endpoints
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/endpoints/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from protorpc import message_types
ImportError: No module named protorpc
>>>
```

Whereas python3 shows the same error the dev appserver is showing.  But I don't see how it could be starting the appengine server as python3 because app.yaml has this:

> runtime: python27

Comment: Can you look in main.py and see that there is indeed an "import endpoints" ... also look through the code to see how that module may be used.  I'm not convinced that the missing module is related to "Google Cloud Endpoints".   The phrase "endpoints" is more generic.

Comment: the first line is "import endpoints" followed by "from endpoints import message".  The pip command in my original post created a folder named "endpoints" in ./lib with an __init__.py in it.  I also have that package installed to my system.  Requirements.txt has "google-endpoints==4.8.0
google-endpoints-api-management==1.11.0".  What's peculiar is that my virtualenv (and system env) recognize endpoints, but not message.  Google's docs indicate this will be the case, and it did work when I built their sample, but not now.

Comment: Do you think it's possible that when I start appengine locally, it's running as python3 and not 2.7?  I added some more details to the original post.

Comment: Your log shows: `Your python27 micro version is below 2.7.12, our current production version.` so no, you're not running python 3 :)

Comment: Do you see endpoints in `python -m pip -t lib list`?

Comment: Yes, but the dev server needs to load from the app's lib folder.  I had forgotten to add the appengine config file that tells it to.

Answer (score 0):

was missing appengine_config.py with:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the `lib` folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```